# Tensorflow Graph Transform Tool quantize_nodes references nonexistant "hat" node names?

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantization

I have been using this simple script to dump out a .pb graph to load up in tensorboard for looking at:

```
import sys
import os
import os.path
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

model_filename = sys.argv[1]
output_dirname = sys.argv[2]

if not os.path.exists(output_dirname):
    os.makedirs(output_dirname)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(output_dirname, tf.get_default_graph())
    writer.close()
```

This works great for visualizing what happens in the graph if you use the graph transform tool up through at least TF 1.2.  When I recently tried master, I get the following problem (using https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception_dec_2015.zip as the graph for example):

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms/transform_graph \
  --in_graph=tensorflow_inception_graph.pb \
  --out_graph=inception_v3_quantized.pb \
  --inputs="Mul" \
  --outputs='softmax' \
  --transforms='add_default_attributes 
    strip_unused_nodes(type=float, shape="1,299,299,3") 
    remove_nodes(op=Identity, op=CheckNumerics)  
    fold_constants(ignore_errors=true) 
    fold_batch_norms 
    fold_old_batch_norms 
    quantize_weights 
    quantize_nodes 
    strip_unused_nodes 
    sort_by_execution_order'
python dump_for_tensorboard.py inception_v3_quantized.pb /tmp/dump_logdir
```

On Tensorflow 1.2 and earlier, this works fine.  I get a directory that I can point tensorboard at.  But on master I get this:

```
2017-12-11 15:56:39.159333: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:137] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../dump_for_tensorboard.py", line 16, in <module>
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 369, in import_graph_def
    'Control input %r not found in graph_def.' % (input_name,)))
ValueError: graph_def is invalid at node u'conv/Conv2D_eightbit/Mul__port__0/reshape_dims': Control input '^Mul:0' not found in graph_def..
```

This also happens in other scripts that I use after using the graph transform tool.

Since this is at the beginning of the graph, I'm not sure whether it has something to do with the input node or whether I would get this for other nodes in the graph also.

On older versions of tensorflow, like the 1.2 branch, this script works fine.

It looks like this might be related to commit d0a5d885 (as this inserts the "^" before the node names) but it is a fairly large merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks like it is tracked here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/14527
and just got merged into master.

If you clone the repo and build the transform_graph tool again, I believe this issue would be fixed now.